# How can I remove a file having name as ABC>DEF.txt?

Tags: unix

It gives error while removing.

It says-

> "rm: ABC: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 6):

Try `rm 'ABC>DEF.txt'`.

The problem is that you shell thinks you are trying to run `rm ABC` save the output (of `rm`) to `DEF.txt`. Quotes should escape the `>`. Have a look at [this](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php) to understand the concept further.

P.S. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1519/how-do-i-delete-a-file-whose-name-begins-with-hyphen-a-k-a-dash-or-minus) semi-related question for many ways to delete oddly named files.

Comment: I know about shell redirection. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just FYI, you should probably use single quotes unless you are sure that whatever you are quoting won't contain any variables that may be expanded. There is not much danger if there is no dollar sign $ but it is not a bad idea to know what you're [quoting](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/)

Comment: Unixbun, That's fine, I'm just erring on the side of more information verses less. @Dmitri, thanks for picking that up, edited.

Answer (score 1):

Unix allows you to use characters in file names that may have special meaning for your user shell---this is how you are able to have spaces in file names, for example.   There are two ways to deal with those characters:

[Escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character):  place the '\' symbol in front of the character--- `rm ABC\>DEF.txt`

[Quoting](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-quoting): `rm 'ABC>DEF.txt'`

Which ever you chose is up to you.